# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in parallel GetObject S3

Tags: c#, ssl, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I want to download files from S3 in parallel.

When I do it non-parallel it works well, but when I tried to change my code to work in parallel (Parallel.For, Task, etc), it always failed with the following error:

> *System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.*

The error occured when trying to execute:

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(Bucket).WithKey(Key);
GetObjectResponse response = amazonS3.GetObject(request);
```

What can cause the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is because AWS S3 is overloaded. It is busy handling too many connections and it is dropping new connections.